# Can not get hours from the date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get hours, minutes and seconds from date but it throws error.

```
class Date extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            hours: '',
            minutes: '',
            seconds: ''
        }
        this.getNewDate = this.getNewDate.bind(this);
    }
    getNewDate(){
        let time = new Date();
        let hours = time.getHours();
        let minutes = time.getMinutes();
        let seconds = time.getSeconds();
        this.setState({
            hours: hours,
            minutes: minutes,
            seconds: seconds
        })
    }
    interval = setInterval(this.getNewDate, 1000);
```

> TypeError: time.getHours is not a function

Comment: Maybe time is a reserved word. Date is for sure

Answer (score 5):

As you called your component `Date`, you shadowed the native `Date` function.

Change the component name.

Comment: Oh yeah thx i thought so. but now i get other error. TypeError: this.setState is not a function. wth

Comment: This a different issue: method bindings (see https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).
In brief: change the signature of from `getNewDate() {` to `getNewDate = () => {`